# Как правильно вывести параметры с базы, с пагинацией

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Вот функция с необходимыми параметрами, как мне правильно вывести в SELECT с сортировкой в обратном порядке?
Вот допустим строка:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
```

Таким образом не работает

```
function selectBlogsFromPostsOnIndex($table, $limit, $offset){
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC ";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    dbCheckError($query);
    return $query->fetchAll();

}
```

Comment: 1. `global $pdo;` лучше не делать так вообще. 2. А вы `$limit` и `$offset` где вообще используете?

Comment: для пагинации в выводе кол-ва записей

Answer (score 0):

1. Для начала правильно подметил Semyon Bayandin в комментариях, что

```
global $pdo;
```

нужно вынести в самое начало инициализации вашего проекта и не в таком формате, а передавать зависимость туда, когда вам нужно

2. Вы не указали limit и offset в вашем sql

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM :table 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql, [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY]);
$query->execute(['table' => $table, 'limit ' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset]);
```

см.документацию: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Серьезно, `FROM :table`?